# What to do in relation to pension funds when leaving Norway?

Tags: pension, norway

I used to work in Norway, but have recently moved to the UK. Is there anything I need to do in relation to my pension funds in Norway? What will happen with my pension funds if I never go back to Norway anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This firstly depends on how long you have lived in Norway and if you are thinking about private or public pension. Within the EU, [most countries](http://www.dwp.gov.uk/international/social-security-agreements/list-of-countries/) fortunately have an agreement over transferring the earned pensions. Both Norway and Great Britain are members of this agreement, i.e. your **public** pension is transfered.

However, a good share of your pension in Norway will be registered with a pension scheme of a private supplier such as the most popular Storebrand or Gjensidige. If you worked in Norway for less then a year, you will loose your entire pension. After this, the payouts depend on your company and contract. Just contact your pension provider and they will be able to tell you.

Comment: If I do not do anything until my retirement age, what will happen with my pension funds?

Comment: Your public funds are accounted to the ones you build up in Britain.

Comment: Do you mean that the transfer will happen automatically without anything to do on my part? When will this happen?

Comment: That is the theory. http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/retire-abroad/state-pensions-abroad/index_en.htm